Countermodel generators for constructive logics
Is there any software out there that can generate countermodels in some form for non-theorems in a constructive logic? I am especially interested in generating countermodels for theorems that are classically valid but constructively invalid.

For intuitionistic propositional calculus, I know of three ways of making a countermodel of a non-theorem by hand. These strategies are super basic and would be straightforward to write a program for if one does not exist already.
If I were to code this up I would probably to use the first two first to get a "small" countermodel before progressing to the modal-logic-based approach.

One is to use a finitely valued logic that satisfies the axioms and inference rules of intuitionistic propositional logic.

Another is to use a topological space, since the class of all topological spaces is a semantics for intuitionistic propositional logic.

Another is to use the usual translation of intuitionistic propositional logic into the modal logic S4, i.e. $\to$ maps to $\square(\lnot \cdot \lor \cdot)$.


However, for first-order constructive logic and beyond I don't know of any strategies for producing a countermodel, let alone one that is easily surveyable by a developer using a proof assistant.
The last time I tried looking into something similar was a few years ago here, but the semantics for first-order intuitionistic logic was beyond my understanding.

SMT solvers?
